# Issue while building crc32

Tags: gcc

I am getting following error while building crc32, I have tried with gcc 4.3,4.4,4.5 and 4.8. Still facing the same issue

```
crc32> make
cc -c crc32be-vx.S
crc32be-vx.S: Assembler messages:
crc32be-vx.S:113: Error: Unrecognized opcode: `lay'
make: *** [crc32be-vx.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be like missing system GNU C Compiler. Installing gcc-z9 solved the issue.